# pendingAlarmIntent.cancel() or AlarmManager.cancel(pendingAlarmIntent)?

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-alarms

I'm just looking at how to cancel an alarm and I came across these two methods. Which one should be used in what situation and why? Are they both the same?

I am currently doing this:

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(ChangeAlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);                         
PendingIntent pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ChangeAlarmActivity.this, (int)alarm.getID(),
        alarmIntent, 0);
pendingAlarmIntent.cancel();
```

How is that different to this below?

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(ChangeAlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);                         
PendingIntent pendingAlarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ChangeAlarmActivity.this, (int)alarm.getID(),
        alarmIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.cancel(pendingAlarmIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are they both the same?

No.

If you want to cancel an alarm, call `cancel()` on `AlarmManager`.

`cancel()` on `PendingIntent` probably will appear to have the same effect -- whatever your alarm events were supposed to trigger no longer happens. However, you are then assuming that `AlarmManager` will detect this and clean things up on its side, which is not guaranteed. Particularly for `_WAKEUP` alarms, this could result in the device being woken up for no good reason, wasting battery life.

> Which one should be used in what situation and why?

I am sure that `cancel()` on `PendingIntent` has use cases. I cannot name any concrete ones, as I have never seen it used. Typically when you are using a `PendingIntent`, any "cancel" semantics are on the *use* of the `PendingIntent` (e.g., you `cancel()` the alarm via `AlarmManager`, you `cancel()` the notification via `NotificationManager`), not on the `PendingIntent` itself.

One place for `cancel()` on `PendingIntent`, therefore, would be some place where you pass off a `PendingIntent` and there is no "cancel" to revert that, or you explicitly wish to use `cancel()` as the revert mechanism. For example, if you are creating some sort of plugin mechanism, and the plugin sends a `PendingIntent` to the host app, the plugin might use `cancel()` to say "stop using that `PendingIntent`", which the host app would find out about the next time it tried to `send()` the `PendingIntent` and got the exception. Personally, I'm not a huge fan of this -- much along the `AlarmManager` lines, you don't know what resources might be used by the host app if it fails to properly handle this scenario. But, used properly, it could certainly work.

> How is that different to this below?

The "below" one is what I would recommend that you use.

Comment: Hmmm, so I tried to cancel with AM to no avail. I have a checkbox to turn an alarm on or off. I am testing turning it off by firstly, saving an alarm with the checkbox not set. This will cause the alarm to be cancelled even though it was not set as I am cancelling the alarm no matter what if the checkbox is not set. I then check the box and save it with the current time to fire the alarm off. This does not work with AM but it does work with PI. In other words, why am I able to cancel an alarm in PI that is not set and then set the alarm afterwards and have it fire off but not with AM?

Comment: @JohnathanAu: That's odd. I am surprised that there was a difference in the first place, and I am even more surprised that `FLAG_NO_CREATE` changed the behavior. The `PendingIntent` for `cancel()` on `AlarmManager` needs to be equivalent, by which I mean that the `Intent` must `filterEquals()` the original `Intent` and it must be for the same operation (activity, service, broadcast).

Comment: I take that back, FLAGS_NO_CREATE works unpredictably, so it doesn't work.